# SPA on GAE. Best way to host frontend

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm developing a Single Page Application on Google App Engine.
The backend will be in Go and the frontend in React.
For the backend I would like to use Google Endpoints. 
This can't be used with a custom domain so I will use CORS:
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9384

But now the question is how should I host the frontend. These are just static files. Should I use a separate GAE project for this? Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

GAE can easily serve static files, just mark them as static in your app.yaml.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/config/appconfig#Go_app_yaml_Static_file_pattern_handlers

> For efficiency, App Engine stores and serves static files separately
>   from application files. Static files are not available in the
>   application's file system.

Example:

```
handlers:

# All URLs ending in .gif .png or .jpg are treated as paths to static files in
# the static/ directory. The URL pattern is a regexp, with a grouping that is
# inserted into the path to the file.
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))$
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg)$
```

I believe they are served from Google's general infrastructure, from a datacenter near to the end user. So it seems like a good idea to do it like this.

In fact for a SPA you will find instances will not spin up if you just serve static files :)

CORS support details also available on that link.

Comment: Yes,  but the frontend needs a custom domain. The backend can't. 2 seperate GAE project then?

Comment: I'm not sure. You could serve content from the backend with the "native" appspot address and add CORS headers so the front-end served code can access it? Not sure TBH.